# How can I find a point on a line when I have only two other points?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

I have a straight line passing from points A(2,-1) and B(4,5). I want to find a point C that is on the line and outside A-B.

Comment: What is the relation between the first, second and third point?

Comment: all 3 should be in straight line

Comment: This isn't a Game development question, it's a simple math question, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
P   &= t (B-A) + A \\
P_x &= t (B_x - A_x) + A_x \\
P_y &= t (B_y - A_y) + A_y \\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\frac {P_x - A_x} {B_x - A_x} = \frac {P_y - A_y} {B_y - A_y}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
P_y &= (P_x - A_x) \times \frac {B_y - A_y} {B_x - A_x} + A_y \\
 &= (P_x - 2) \times \frac {5 - -1} {4 - 2} + -1 \\
 &= (P_x - 2) \times \frac 6 2 - 1 \\
 &= (P_x - 2) \times 3 - 1 \\
 &= 3 \times P_x - 6 - 1 \\
 &= 3 \times P_x - 7
\end{align}
$$

\$A\$ and \$B\$ are points. In this case \$A\$ = (2, -1), \$B\$ = (4,5)
\$P\$ is the point you are looking for.

\$A_x\$ is the coordinate \$x\$ of point \$A\$. In this case \$A_x = 2\$.

[image]

Comment: In first eqn you write P=t * (B-A) and x=t * (Bx-Ax) so what is Bx and Ax? I am unable to understand plz explain.

Comment: would you tell me how c=2 arrives?

Comment: I am very close to solution plz explain how c=2 is calculated?

Comment: i have introduced C to show you visually how can you get a point in a line based on two known points. You can multiply (B-A) by whatever factor "t" and you will get points in that line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have point A on coordinates (2,-1) and B on (4,5). You want to find point C, if you know for example x coordinate?

You can compute direction vector from A to B, which is: B - A = (2, 6), then normalize it, so you get: (1/sqrt(10), 3/sqrt(10)). If you have for example that x coordinate of point C (lets say its for example 8), you divide this by x coordinate of direction vector and multiplz by y coordinate of direction vector. You get: 8 / 1 * 3 = 24. So point C has coordinates (10, 24).

Comment: I don't know what is the term normalize and how can i do it? plz help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector You just divide each coordinate of vector by length of vector (length = sqrt(x*x + y*y))

Answer (score 0):

To find points that lay on a line that passes through two known points you use [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_between_two_known_points).

Comment: but i don't want to find third point between the two points i want to find the third point outside the two points

Comment: To do that you just need to pass e.g. t=2 to your interpolation function.